# Show data obtained from field in ajax by console

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, console

I am new using ajax with PHP I need to send data by field and show it by console but it does not work for me. Can you help me what version of jquery should I use to make the script work?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 

<input type="text" name="box" id="box" class="box" value="">
<input type="button" name="boton01" id="boton01" value="Buttom">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#boton01').click(function(){
        var result=$('#box').val();
        console.log(result);
    })
});
```

console show

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "alias" `jQuery` with the `$` to use it otherwise you should be able to just swap our the `$` with `jQuery` and all should work for you:

```
// use self invoking function and pass in jQuery then alias it with $
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#boton01').click(function(){
            var result = $('#box').val();
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

OR

```
// use jQuery in place of $
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#boton01').click(function(){
        var result = jQuery('#box').val();
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```